# Candump (SocketCAN) ID range filtering feature

Tags: can-bus, bitmask

I need to filter ranges of IDs ([0x5B to 0x7B] + [0x87 to 0xCC]) and i'm confused with bitmasking to do it:

For the first range, i tried :
candump vcan0,5B:7DF
which let throw only 0x5B and 0x7B messages, not the range.

Any help how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First let's clarify why `5B:7DF` shows 0x5B and 0x7B only. You're basically masking the following:

```
b00001011011 <- 0x5B
b11111011111 <- 0x7DF (mask)
------------
b00001011011 <- bitwise AND
```

Only messages that give the same result by masking with 0x7DF will be let through. Given there is only one zero in 0x7DF, only 0x7B will work:

```
b00001111011 <- 0x7B
b11111011111 <- 0x7DF (mask)
------------
b00001011011 <- bitwise AND
```

Now let's add zeros to the right side of your mask:

```
b00001011011 <- 0x5B
b11111000000 <- 0x7C0 (mask) (edit : fix typo copy/paste)
------------
b00001000000 <- bitwise AND
```

Following the same logic, this mask will let messages through with IDs from b00001000000 (0x40) to b00001111111 (0x7F).

As you can see, bit-masks are not very well adapted to this kind of range (hex/dec). It's easier for instance to filter out 0x182, 0x282, 0x382 and 0x482 (hence the distribution of PDO-IDs in [CANopen](https://www.can-cia.org/fileadmin/resources/documents/brochures/co_poster.pdf)).
Your best bet is to split your range in binary friendly slices:

- 0x5B (b1011011)
- 0x5C to 0x5F (b1011100 to b1011111)
- 0x60 to 0x6F (b1100000 to b1101111)
- etc...